# Scrubbing Past "Viewport Visibility" Keyframe in Timeline Unselects my Object, Causing All Keyframes/Channels to Disappear

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, timeline, visibility

In 2.93.3 (haven't tested this in other versions), when I have a Grease Pencil object in Draw mode, and have a viewport visibility keyframe set on the grease pencil object itself (set via Object Properties), as soon as I scrub past where the visibility keyframe is in the timeline, not only does the grease pencil object disappear from view, as it should, but it also becomes unselected at the same time, which I don't want it to do. This is because, in becoming unselected, its keyframes no longer display in the timeline. What's more, I can't reselect it at this stage to get the view of its keyframes back, because it's invisible in the viewport. I can scrub back to the point before it became invisible, and it reappears, but is still unselected, and must be manually selected again before its keyframes reappear in the timeline.

I'm trying to discover a workflow for doing cut-out style 2D animation, which, in my experience, makes use of a lot of object hiding trickery to make everything work visually. Blender seems to be fighting me every step of the way, and this is only the latest headache.

What am I supposed to do to achieve a straightforward workflow that includes hiding objects temporarily in 2D animation? I clearly can't get viewport hiding to work in a way that lets me keep working after the effect has been added to the timeline, for the above-stated reason. Maybe some solution having to do with view layers and collections? How would that workflow be different from this one? Is it straightforward or complicated? How many workarounds will it require?

In case anyone is wondering why I don't confine my visibility changes to layers within the Grease Pencil object, it's because I want this object controlled by a separate bone, so that it can have an action clip associated with it, to the exclusion of anything else in the scene.

Note: I would be happy to set renderability keyframes instead of viewport visibility keyframes (and in fact, I'm already setting renderability keyframes anyway, ones which coincide with the viewport visibility keyframes I'm trying to get working) in order to bypass this issue. However, setting viewport display to "Rendered" View doesn't seem to mean I will then be able to see keyframed renderability changes on the fly, within the viewport. It doesn't seem to do this. So that solution is out.